# Odd /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php entries showing in Wassup

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I have an odd issue going on that I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

Ever since I installed a popular post plugin (Wordpress Popular Posts) I have been seeing a strange entry in Wassup real time analytics to a page called /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php over and over again.  Before I installed the plugin it would show the page that was being hit but it looks like for whatever reason this page is getting hit instead and I am unable to see what page the user is actually hitting.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

EDIT: **How do I get the correct page/post to be displayed instead of this?**

I have looked throught the settings in Wassup and as far as I can tell there is no way to correct this through the plugin.  Is there a better plugin to use for tracking top posts that will alleviate this issue?  I have tried a few other plugins but have had no luck correcting the problem.  I just want something that I know will work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

`/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` is the callback file for the WordPress [Ajax API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). I am assuming, but I am fairly confident, that your plugin is using that API (as it should be). It isn't an issue. You have to have an AJAX call load some file. WordPress just standardized that location. Despite its location in `/wp-admin` that same file is used by both front end, no-priviledge AJAX and logged-in user admin AJAX.

Comment: Ok so the plugin is working how it should, that's good.  But how then do I go about seeing the correct analytic information here instead of the Ajax API call?

Comment: That is a different question. You are now asking how to configure Wassup (or that plugin), and I don't know.

Comment: That's sort of what I was afraid of.  I wasn't quite sure how to ask this originally.

Comment: If the plugin is configurable you could edit the question to specify that that is what you need. If this is a matter of configuring your Wassup account, that will be off topic.

Comment: I will give you upvote and just edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution I ended up finding.  I had WP Super Cache enabled (which I was unaware of originally).  So I disabled Super Cache, then I disabled the Wassup plugin and then finally enabled the Wassup plugin again and the stat collection is working correctly now.